# Set Return type from multiple objects for a procedure in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a procedure in place of a join between a view and table using LINQ C#. But in order to use a procedure without changing the entire logic I am trying to use return type from both view and table. But I am only able to take return type from one object either table or view. Is there a way where we can take return type from multiple objects for a procedure. Below is my LINQ code for setting up return type for the procedure.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.USP_Procedure")]
        public ISingleResult<V_View_Object1> USP_Procedure()
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
            return ((ISingleResult<V_View_Object1>)(result.ReturnValue));//returning fields from view only I want to return from table and view both

        }
```

I am trying to return fields from a table(Table_Object2) with the v_View_object1. Is there a way to do this? Does LinQ allow this? Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a LINQ issue. The return type of your method is `ISingleResult<V_View_Object1>` so you must return that. If you want to return something else, you need to change the return type and deal with that at all calling locations. Also, where is `Table_Object2` in your code?

Comment: @NetMage Table_Object2 is under same dbml in which the view and procedure are. I am taking the return type from the view and Was thinking to return both table and view fields instead of just view. But I guess thats not possible, So I will have to define all the returning fields manually for that procedure now.

Comment: What does your SQL stored procedure return?

Comment: @NetMage it returns all the fields from the view and the table. I fixed it. I defined all the fields for procedure and used the procedure as Enumerable and its working as expected. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have two output parameters in your stored procedure. LINQ does not support table-valued parameters in stored procedures, so it would only be possible to retrieve data from the result set of the query joining the table and the view.